# model evaluation with "train_test_split" not static?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

According to the resources online "train_test_split" function from sklearn.cross_validation module returns data in a random state.

Does this mean if I train a model with the same data twice, I am getting two different models since the training data points used in the learning process is different in each case?

In practice can the accuracy of such two models differ a lot? Is that a possible scenario?

Comment: You can set the seed to some constant if you want to have reproducible behaviour, but still based on random-splits (this is a basic uage-pattern of PRNGs). If you don't do this, probably time-based seeding is used and results will be different. There is no theoretical limit on these differences in general. It could be catastrophic in theory (depending on the classifier used).

Answer (score 1):

You can set `random_state` parameter to some constant value to reproduce data splits. On the other hand, it's generally a good idea to test exactly what you are trying to know - i.e. run your training at least twice with different randoms states and compare the results. If they differ a lot it's a sign that something is wrong and your solution is not reliable.